# Need help in POST multiple image file using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

How to add multiple images/files on a same parameter along with other textual data using retrofit?

```
Single image is uploading perfectly using following interface
    @Multipart
    @POST("/users/updateProfile/")
    public void updateProfileWithImage(
                    @Part("user_id") TypedString first_name,
                    @Part ("image") TypedFile image, 
                    Callback<WebResponse> callback);
```

Comment: do you have an example of what your using now to add a single image?

Comment: Just add more `@Part` parameters to the method. You're on the right track already.

Comment: But how will add images dynamically from arrayList adapter to a @Part. As @Part("image") ArrayList<TypedFile> images is not posting files.

Comment: How to use this approach in iOS???

Answer (score 12):

You can use the @MultiPart Post with **@PartMap as parameter**

```
Map<String, TypedFile> files = new HashMap<String, TypedFile>();
files.put("my file number one", new TypedFile("image/jpg", new File(filename)));
files.put("my file number two", new TypedFile("image/jpg", new File(filename)));

apiInterface.updateProfileWithImage("first name here", files);

private interface ApiInterface{
    @Multipart
    @POST("/users/updateProfile/")
    Response updateProfileWithImage(
     @Part("user_id") TypedString first_name,
     @PartMap Map<String,TypedFile> Files
    );

}
```

Comment: In twitter, we need to specify the same file name for that, 
`files.put("media[]", file);
files.put("media[]", file);`
So, here comes the problem of not uploading multiple files.
@Francois Any solution to this ?

Comment: @YashSodha did you find a solution?

Comment: @BorisTreukhov nope, instead I had to set off with multiple tweets with different pic

Comment: @YashSodha actually MultipartTypedOutput solved the problem, thanks. The only thing I missed was the square brackets.

Comment: one question @francois what if i wanna send multiple files with same name then how to do that as in map it has unique key therefore if i will add suppose 5 files with same name it will contain only one file with that name rest will be deleted from the map??

Answer (score 12):

**Retrofit 2.0 + OkHttp 3**

Interface declaration:

```
@POST("postpath")
Call<Void> upload(@Body MultipartBody filePart);
```

Creating `MultiPartBody`:

```
MultipartBody.Builder requestBodyBuilder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
```

then for each file(you can also add custom fields)

```
requestBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("extraImage[]", "photo.jpg",
                            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), byteArrayOrFile));
```

and finally

```
api.upload(requestBodyBuilder.build());
```

P.S. you can add custom form fields (for example `client.name`) to the same form with

```
requestBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("client[name]", null, RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), name))
```

or

```
requestBodyBuilder.addFormDataPart("client[name]", name))
```

**Retrofit 1.9**:

You can use MultipartTypedOutput to post variable number of multi-part parameters.

In addition to François' answer, to post multiple images with *the same / repeating* field name(as an array) in retrofit you can use **MultipartTypedOutput**

Method signature:

```
@POST("/postpath")
SomeResponse upload(@Body MultipartTypedOutput output);
```

Usage:

```
MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput = new MultipartTypedOutput();
multipartTypedOutput.addPart("mainImage", new TypedFile("image/jpeg", mainImage));
multipartTypedOutput.addPart("extraImage[]", new TypedFile("image/jpeg", file1));
multipartTypedOutput.addPart("extraImage[]", new TypedFile("image/jpeg", file2));
upload(multipartTypedOutput);
```

**Square brackets**

Please note that some server side frameworks(Rails) typically require square brackets(i.e. `extraImage[]` instead of `extraImage`), others don't (Spring MVC).

Comment: Do i have to use @Multipart above POST to use this ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur In case of using`@Body MultipartTypedOutput` argument, **NO**.