# "Retrofit" multiple images attached in one multipart request

Tags: android, multipart, retrofit

Is there any way to attached multiple images in one multipart request? The images is dynamic based on the number of images that user has picked.

Below code only works for single image:

Interface:

```
@Multipart
@POST("/post")
void createPostWithAttachments( @Part("f[]") TypedFile image,@PartMap Map<String, String> params,Callback<String> response);
```

Implementation:

```
TypedFile file = new TypedFile("image/jpg", new File(gallery.sdcardPath));

Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
params.put("key","value");

ServicesAdapter.getAuthorizeService().createPostWithAttachments(file,params, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            DBLogin.updateCookie(response);
            new_post_text.setText("");
            try {
                JSONObject json_response = new JSONObject(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (json_response.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                    JSONObject dataObj = json_response.getJSONObject("data");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Request failed");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), retrofitError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After look around with the documentation that provided by retrofit..
Im able to get it done by my own solution, maybe is not that good but still manage to get it works..

**Here is the referece** [MultipartTypedOutput](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/index.html?retrofit/mime/MultipartTypedOutput.html)

Actually is quite similar to the previous code from above, just make a little bit changes

**Interface**

```
@POST("/post")
void createPostWithAttachments( @Body MultipartTypedOutput attachments,Callback<String> response);
```

**Implementation**

```
    MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput = new MultipartTypedOutput();
    multipartTypedOutput.addPart("c", new TypedString(text));
    multipartTypedOutput.addPart("_t", new TypedString("user"));
    multipartTypedOutput.addPart("_r", new TypedString(userData.user.id));

    //loop through object to get the path of the images that has picked by user
    for(int i=0;i<attachments.size();i++){
        CustomGallery gallery = attachments.get(i);
        multipartTypedOutput.addPart("f[]",new TypedFile("image/jpg",new File(gallery.sdcardPath)));
    }

    ServicesAdapter.getAuthorizeService().createPostWithAttachments(multipartTypedOutput, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            DBLogin.updateCookie(response);
            new_post_text.setText("");
            try {
                JSONObject json_response = new JSONObject(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json_response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (json_response.getString("status").equals("success")) {
                    JSONObject dataObj = json_response.getJSONObject("data");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Request failed");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), retrofitError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Maybe this solution is not that good but hopes it help someone else.

If there is any better solution please suggest, thank you :D

### Updates

**MultipartTypedOutput** no longer exists in Retrofit 2.0.0-beta1

For those who want to upload multiple images now can use with **@PartMap**, reference link [javadoc](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/PartMap.html)

Comment: This worked great for me where I needed parts with the same name, but different values. Similar to an array, but the name could not have the "[]" with it and a new part.

Comment: works like a charm. thanks man!! Note: Don't forget to remove @Multipart annotation when using Body and POST!

Comment: in my case MultipartTypedOutput is running slower than part i dont know why this is happening can you please tell me ??

Comment: Man please please tell me how you pick the images i dont umderstand the loop part, im about to lose my mind on this last feauter in my app

Comment: any solution for retrofit 2, since this does not work?

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov See a dupe question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658797/need-help-in-post-multiple-image-file-using-retrofit/32275127#32275127

Answer (score 4):

```
//We need to create the Typed file array as follow and add the images path in the arrays list.



    private ArrayList<TypedFile> images;

        private void postService(final Context context) {
            Utils.progressDialog(context);
            MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput = new MultipartTypedOutput();
            multipartTypedOutput.addPart("user_id",new TypedString(strUserId));
            multipartTypedOutput.addPart("title", new TypedString(strJobtitle));
            multipartTypedOutput.addPart("description", new TypedString(
                    strJobdescription));
            multipartTypedOutput.addPart("experience", new TypedString(
                    strUserExperience));
            multipartTypedOutput.addPart("category_id", new TypedString(
                    strPostCategory));
            multipartTypedOutput.addPart("city_id", new TypedString(strCityCode));
            multipartTypedOutput.addPart("country_id", new TypedString(
                    strCountryCode));       
    multipartTypedOutput.addPart("profile_doc",new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", postCurriculamFile));
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                multipartTypedOutput.addPart("image[]", images.get(i));
    }       

    PostServiceClient.getInstance().postServiceData(multipartTypedOutput,
                    new Callback<RegistrationResponsModel>() {
                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    Logger.logMessage("fail" + retrofitError);
                    Utils.progressDialogdismiss(context);
                }

                @Override
                public void success(
                        RegistrationResponsModel regProfileResponse,
                        Response arg1) {
                    Utils.progressDialogdismiss(context);
                    UserResponse(regProfileResponse);
                }
            });
        }


    @POST("/service/update") // annotation used to post the data
    void postEditServiceData(@Body MultipartTypedOutput attachments, 
            Callback<RegistrationResponsModel> callback);
```

//This is the way we can post the file
multipartTypedOutput.addPart("profile_doc",new TypedFile("multipart/form-data", postCurriculamFile));

//This is the way we can post the multiple images

```
    for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
        multipartTypedOutput.addPart("image[]", images.get(i));
    }
```

Comment: Seems interisting but what method is this postCurriculamFile? Im using usual gallery intent to select each image can you point me please

Comment: postCurriculamFile is the path of the document and the path file gets through Intent.if your posting images means no need of this line.                   if (fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("application/pdf")     || fileType.equalsIgnoreCase("doc")) {
      Utils.savePreferences(context, "postservicefile", path);
      
     }

Comment: Thanks for replay actually I created a volley request for params and within it onresponse a retrofit request for images, it works fine but its a safe code?

Comment: Implementation its seems fine and its a safe code but the optimization perspective better go with retro fit.you can achieve both the image and param request.

Comment: Hard to understand it and im in harry it didnt work alone or i couldnt make it