# Wont be able to upload image into the server

Tags: android

I want to upload image into the database(c panel) in File format.For doing this at first I select an image from gallery or capture an image,set the image in an imageview and try to pass the image as an input parameter through api. But wont be able to send the image file.

**Select image**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                    cameraIntent();
                else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                    galleryIntent();
            } else {
                //code for deny
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library", "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProfileActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(ProfileActivity.this);

            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                if(result)
                    cameraIntent();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                userChoosenTask ="Choose from Library";
                if(result)
                    galleryIntent();

            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void galleryIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
}

private void cameraIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

    FileOutputStream fo;
    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    iv_profile.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    ProfileImageAPI api = new ProfileImageAPI(this,this);
    api.processProfileImage(AppController.getInstance().userId,destination,"photo.jpg");

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    iv_profile.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

}

**api.php**

```
function process_updateUserProfileImage()
{
    $user_id         = isset($_REQUEST['user_id'])?$_REQUEST['user_id']:"";

    if($user_id == "" ){
        echo json_encode(array("error"=>"1", "error_type"=>"user updateUserProfile", "error_no" => "1009", "error_message" => "Input validation"));
        exit;
    }

             $file_name = "";
             $file_url = "";

             if($_FILES["profile_image"]["name"]!="")
             { 
                 $file_name=time().$_FILES["profile_image"]["name"];
                 $tmp_name=$_FILES["profile_image"]["tmp_name"];
                 $file_type=$_FILES['profile_image']['type'];
                 $file_size=$_FILES['profile_image']['size'];
                 $upload_dir="../profile_image/";

                 fileUpload($upload_dir,$file_name,$tmp_name,$file_size,"image");
                 MakeThumbnail($upload_dir, $file_name ,100,100);   

                 $file_url = SITE_URL.'profile_image/'.$file_name;
             }

            $sql = "update user set
                `profile_image`     = '".trim($file_url)."'
                 where user_id      = '".$user_id."'
                ";

            $rs = mysql_query($sql);


            /*$userArr = array("success"=>"1", "sucess_type"=>"user registration", "success_message" => "User successfully registered");*/
            $userInfo = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from user where user_id = ".$user_id));


            $userArr = array();

            $userArr =  array('user_id'=>$userInfo['user_id'],'profile_image'=>$userInfo['profile_image'],"success_message" => "profile image updated successfully");
            echo json_encode($userArr);
            exit();

}
```

**ProfileImageApi class**

```
public class ProfileImageAPI extends BaseAPI {

private Context mContext;
private NetworkCallback mCallback;

public ProfileImageAPI(Context context, NetworkCallback callback) {
    super(context);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mCallback = callback;
}
public void processProfileImage(final String userId, final File profileImg, final String imgName){
    showProgressDialog();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            ApiUtil.BASE_EDIT_PROFILE_IMAGE, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(ApiUtil.TAG_EDIT_PROFILE_IMAGE, response.toString());

            mCallback.updateScreen(response,ApiUtil.TAG_EDIT_PROFILE_IMAGE);
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(ApiUtil.TAG_EDIT_PROFILE_IMAGE, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            mCallback.updateScreen("ERROR",ApiUtil.TAG_EDIT_PROFILE_IMAGE);
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(ApiUtil.PARAM_USER_ID,userId);
            params.put(ApiUtil.PARAM_PROFILE_IMG,profileImg.toString());
            params.put(ApiUtil.PARAM_IMG_NAME,imgName);
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController ctrl = AppController.getInstance();
    ctrl.addToRequestQueue(strReq, ApiUtil.TAG_EDIT_PROFILE_IMAGE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Which library you have used for api calls.
1. Retrofit
2. Okhttp.

Retrofit MultiPartWebservice : ["Retrofit" multiple images attached in one multipart request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249042/retrofit-multiple-images-attached-in-one-multipart-request)
OKHttp MultiPartWebservice :
[how to use okhttp to upload a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512547/how-to-use-okhttp-to-upload-a-file)

Comment: I have used Volley.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity

Comment: check above link i think i will help you

Comment: @MavyaSoni Which answer did you find helpful?  I'm having difficulties with the two that I tried, especially the kotlin answer (which is what I'm programming in).