# Android Retrofit : POST Request with JSON payload and Images Attached

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm using Square's Retrofit library in my app. I need to POST to a particular endpoint. There is to be a JSON payload, an Authorization header as well as images attached. My image files are currently in the Pictures Directory.

```
POST("/" + ENDPOINT_POST_PICTURE_SET)
@Multipart
SendPictureSetResponse sendPictureSet(@Header("Authorization") 
String token, @Part("key1") TypedString value1,
@Part("key2") TypedString value2,
@PartMap Map<Integer, TypedFile> files);
```

I referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26735421/1606296. However, 
I get a

```
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such   file or directory)
```

even though those files exist. Another issue is that I cannot see the payload in the logs(I tried adding a `@body` parameter : It says I cannot add this to a multipart request.) 
I have added files(images that I saved taken from the camera to a folder in the pictures directory), by using

```
Map<Integer, TypedFile> files = new HashMap<Integer, TypedFile>();
files.put(0, new TypedFile("image/jpg", 
new File(application.getImageFilePaths().get(0))));
        files.put(1, new TypedFile("image/jpg", 
new  File(application.getImageFilePaths().get(1))));
        files.put(2, new TypedFile("image/jpg", 
new File(application.getImageFilePaths().get(2))));
```

EDIT : Stack Trace

```
07-04 01:07:13.501  27594-27705/com.rohanmahale.test D/Retrofit﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/TestApp/Current/TestApp_20150704_010712.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
        at retrofit.mime.TypedFile.writeTo(TypedFile.java:74)
        at  retrofit.mime.MultipartTypedOutput$MimePart.writeTo(MultipartTypedOutput.java:54)
at retrofit.mime.MultipartTypedOutput.writeTo(MultipartTypedOutput.java:144)
        at retrofit.Utils.readBodyToBytesIfNecessary(Utils.java:62)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter.logAndReplaceRequest(RestAdapter.java:438)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:317)
        at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
        at $Proxy0.sendPictureSet(Unknown Source)
        at com.rohanmahale.test.helpers.WebServicesHelper.sendPicturesToServer(WebServicesHelper.java:79)
        at com.rohanmahale.test.fragments.DemoCameraFragment.sendPicsToServer(DemoCameraFragment.java:300)
        at com.rohanmahale.test.fragments.DemoCameraFragment_.access$201(DemoCameraFragment_.java:28)
        at com.rohanmahale.test.fragments.DemoCameraFragment_$6.execute(DemoCameraFragment_.java:172)
        at org.androidannotations.api.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:393)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
at retrofit.mime.TypedFile.writeTo(TypedFile.java:74)
    at retrofit.mime.MultipartTypedOutput$MimePart.writeTo(MultipartTypedOutput.java:54)
    at retrofit.mime.MultipartTypedOutput.writeTo(MultipartTypedOutput.java:144)
            at retrofit.Utils.readBodyToBytesIfNecessary(Utils.java:62)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter.logAndReplaceRequest(RestAdapter.java:438)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:317)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
            at $Proxy0.sendPictureSet(Unknown Source)
            at com.rohanmahale.test.helpers.WebServicesHelper.sendPicturesToServer(WebServicesHelper.java:79)
            at com.rohanmahale.test.fragments.DemoCameraFragment.sendPicsToServer(DemoCameraFragment.java:300)
            at com.rohanmahale.test.fragments.DemoCameraFragment_.access$201(DemoCameraFragment_.java:28)
            at com.rohanmahale.test.fragments.DemoCameraFragment_$6.execute(DemoCameraFragment_.java:172)
            at org.androidannotations.api.BackgroundExecutor$Task.run(BackgroundExecutor.java:393)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-04 01:07:13.501  27594-27705/com.rohanmahale.test D/Retrofit﹕ ---- END ERROR
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: post full stacktrace.

Comment: @njzk2    Added the stack trace.

Comment: it would seem your files don't exist.

Comment: @njzk2 The files definitely exist. I can see them in that particular folder. In fact.. I display the images in the following activity using picasso.

Comment: @njzk2. You were right. There is a bug in the code..The third image was not getting saved which was the issue for the file not found exception. How do I now add a JSON payload to this request. I have to send a few K,V pairs.

Comment: add them in your map, possibly as typed strings

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

```
@POST("/" + ENDPOINT_POST_PICTURE_SET)
void sendPictureSet(@Body MultipartTypedOutput attachments,Callback<String> response)
```

For the MulipartTypedOutput, I used

```
 MultipartTypedOutput multipartTypedOutput = new MultipartTypedOutput();
 multipartTypedOutput.addPart("imageArray[]", new TypedFile("image/jpg", new File(application.getImageFilePaths().get(0))));
 multipartTypedOutput.addPart("imageArray[]", new TypedFile("image/jpg", new File(application.getImageFilePaths().get(1))));
 multipartTypedOutput.addPart("imageArray[]", new TypedFile("image/jpg", new File(application.getImageFilePaths().get(2))));
 multipartTypedOutput.addPart("key2", new TypedString("val2"));
```

Thanks to @Louis Loo, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25260556/1606296